# Why this polynomial reducible? (composite field)

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, galois-extensions

In galois field of prime 2, in composite field $GF((({2}^2)^2)^2)$,

There are irreducible polynomials and reducible polynomials.

$GF(2^2):Q_1(x) = x^2+x+1,$

$GF((2^2)^2):Q_2(x) = x^2+x+\phi,$ $\alpha$ is the root of $Q_2(x)$, $\phi \in GF(2^2)$

$GF((2^2)^2)^2):Q_3(x) = x^2+x+\lambda,$ $\lambda \in GF((2^2)^2)$

Combinations of $\phi$ and $\lambda$ constructs the field.

I tried to figure out the combination $\phi=\{10\}$ and $\lambda=\{1010\}$ is reducible $(\lambda =\alpha^9$ at $GF((2^2)^2))$, but cannot find the pair that makes polynomial $Q_3(x)$ reducible.

Is there any pair that makes this polynomial reducible?

---

$\phi$ can be expressed as $\{1\}X^1 + \{0\}X^0$

$\lambda$ can be expressed as $(\{1\}X^1+\{0\}X^0)Y^1 + (\{1\}X^1+\{0\}X^0)Y^0$

Element of $GF((2^2)^2)^2)$ can be expressed as

$((a_7X^1+a_6X^0)Y^1+(a_5X^1+a_4X^0)Y^0)Z^1+((a_3X^1+a_2X^0)Y^1+(a_1X^1+a_0X^0)Y^0)Z^0$,$\{a_7 a_6 a_5 a_4 a_3 a_2 a_1 a_0\}$.

Representation is different to $GF(2^8)$

Comment: Why write $((2^2)^2)^2$ instead of $2^8$?

Comment: Since we don't know the relations between $\phi$, $\lambda$, and $\alpha$, it is hard to say. But if $\phi \in \mathrm{GF}(2^{4})$, then $Q_{2}$ must be reducible in $\mathrm{GF}(2^{8})$. Likewise with $\lambda$ and $Q_{3}$.

Comment: @lhf Because $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ is different to $GF(2^8)$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers $\phi \in GF(2^2)$, not in $GF(2^4)$

Comment: $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)=GF(2^8)$. You probably meant $\phi \in GF(2^4),\not\in GF(2)$ and similarly for $\lambda$ ? With a counting argument and the fact that the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)(x-a^2)$ we get that not all polynomial of the form $x^2+x+b,b\in GF(2^n),\not\in GF(2^{n-1})$ is irreducible in $GF(2^n)[x]$.

Comment: @reuns You totally don't understand the composite field. Please write after you know the composite field. And $Q_2(x)$ and $Q_3(x)$ is extension field polynomials

Comment: There is only one field with $2^8$ elements but many different ways to represent it. You want to construct it as a tower of quadratic extensions $GF(2^8)/GF(2^4)/GF(2^2)/GF(2)$ so you need to find an irreducible quadratic polynomial at each step.

Comment: @reuns Well, elements are isomorphic with different polynomials, for example, $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^1+1$(Advanced Encryption Standard polynomial). What I want to ask is why that combinations of $Q_2(x)$ and $Q_3(x)$ is reducible.

Comment: First of all you meant $\phi$ a root of $x^2+x+1$. So the first question is if $x^2+x+\phi$ is irreducible. For this try it : for each $a,b\in GF(2)^2$ find if $(a+b\phi)^2+(a+b\phi)+\phi=0\in GF(2)[\phi]/(\phi^2+\phi+1)$. What I'm saying is that a counting argument shows that we can't say if the polynomial is irreducible just by looking at it.

Comment: Pyong, calm down. It is well known from elementary course on abstract algebra that all fields with $2^8$ elements are isomorphic, and thus it makes perfect sense to state that $GF(2^8)=GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$. We also know that some implementations of the arithmetic of these fields benefit from having this construction as quadratic towers. The fields are *the same*, but the interpretations of elements as strings of bits are different.

Comment: Anyway, one way of constructing this tower is outlined in [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/166932/11619).

Comment: (cont'd) It goes as follows. $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$ so if we denote by $\alpha_1$ its zero, then $\alpha_1$ generates the extension $GF(2^2)$. It is not hard to show that $x^2+x+\alpha_1$ is irreducible over $GF(2^2)$. So if we denote by $\alpha_2$ its zero, we see that $\alpha_2$ generates the extension $GF((2^2)^2)$ over either $GF(2)$ (degree four) or over $GF(2^2)$ (degree two). And we can keep going. $x^2+x+\alpha_2$ is irreducible over $GF((2^2)^2)$, and its zero $\alpha_3$ gives us $GF(2^8)$ etc.

Comment: But, may be you could explain the meaning of the notations such as $\{10\}$ and $\{1010\}$. They may be standard in your line of work, but they are anything but standard to users best placed to help you with the algebra. I can guess that the notations captures both halves of an element of some quadratic tower, and that the left/right halves are the coordinates w.r.t. a basis, and represent elements of the previous field. But there are at least little/big endian problems in interpreting those bit strings.

Comment: OK. I guess the last part tries to explain that. Thanks. Actually there is still a problem of the choice of basis, but that answers the little/big endian question.

Comment: The $X,Y,Z$ feel a bit strange to me because we are to do a recursive construction and will run out of dstinct letters sooner or later :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Then how can I change $X, Y, Z$ to standard representation with recursive construction? $X, Y, Z$ are used because David Canright(in AES Sbox optimization, using normal basis of $2^8$) showed $GF(((2^2)^2)^2)$ normal basis representation similar to my representation though Canright used greek alphabet to represent.

Comment: If you are stuck with a given way of doing $GF(256)$ then stick to it. My criticisim of using $X,Y,Z$ was more about extending this to $GF(2^{128})$. You need seven "letters" :-) Anyway, I will compose an answer. I cannot guarantee that it will be compatible with Canright's.

Comment: Sorry about abandoning my answer here. I sort of fleshed it out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739892/11619), but I'm not sure it covers everything.